# Is there a way to debug the worker processes in pm2 while application is running in Cluster mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, pm2, node-inspector

So I have a `node.js` application which I am running in `cluster mode` using `pm2`. I am passing the following options for the web node in my `pm2` schema.

```
exec-mode : "cluster"
--node-args : ["--inspect=5678"]
```

and for worker node I am passing following configuration

```
--node-args=["--inspect=5679"]
```

When I start my application in `cluster mode`, debugging is not possible as I cannot see the debugging URL printed in `pm2` logs. Even if I send the USR1 signal to the web or worker node (as mentioned in [node inspector help](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/)), I do not see any way to debug the processes.

My guess is that in `cluster mode`, debugging `node.js` is not possible. I tried the same process with `node-inspector` but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the node_args as a string instead of array (eg --node-args="--inspect=1234")

Comment: I tried that also. It does not make any difference.